# Powershell find and move file

Tags: powershell, find, move

I have a long list of find and move operations, I want to slim down the script by substituting the following 2 long commands with 2 short variables.

Short variables:

```
$f = 'Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter'
$m = 'Move-Item -Force -Verbose -Destination V:\MSL\_pdf\'
```

Long commands:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter GAS*.pdf | Move-Item -Force -Verbose -Destination V:\MSL\_pdf\GAS
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter GCA_00*.pdf | Move-Item -Force -Verbose -Destination V:\MSL\_pdf\GCA\GCA_00
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter GCA_01*.pdf | Move-Item -Force -Verbose -Destination V:\MSL\_pdf\GCA\GCA_01
```

And this doesn't work:

```
$f GAS*.pdf | $m`GAS
$f GCA_00*.pdf | $m`GCA\GCA_00
$f GCA_01*.pdf | $m`GCA\GCA_01
```

Comment: that is what functions are for ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Lee said in the comment, you should use function:

```
function GetAndMove($files, $dest)
{
   $dest = "V:\MSL\_pdf\$($dest)"
   Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter $files | Move-Item -Force -Verbose -Destination $dest
}

# Now call the function
GetAndMove "GAS*.pdf" "GAS"
GetAndMove "GCA_00*" "GCA\GCA_00"
GetAndMove "GCA_01*" "GCA\GCA_01"
```

...

Comment: Since I now have more than 50 lines of GetAndMove, can I put one GetAndMove function  at the start and have an array with the parameters only?

Comment: Yes, in the function get the array, loop on him and do the move, then call it one time and send the array.

Comment: Would you be so nice to actually write such code, thanks a lot